# Error in creating AdCreative using Facebook ads API

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-ads-api

I'm trying to create an ad creative using Facebook ads api, but failed because of missing 'title' param. I did have a 'title' param in the request. Here is the debug log.

url: https://graph.facebook.com/act_xxx/adcreatives
params: Array
(

```
[object_store_url] => https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/game-of-war-fire-age/id667728512
[image_hash] => xxx
[actor_name] => Game of War - Fire Age
[title] => Game of War - Fire Age
[body] => Play for Free!!
[actor_image_hash] => abc
[icon_image_hash] => abc
[type] => 32
[method] => POST
[access_token] => xxxx
```

)

2014-03-14 10:43:25: Facebook API Error: Exception: The Adcreative Create Failed for the following reason: missing a required attribute: Required attribute "title" was not provided. [CODE:1487390]

Answer (score 0):

Actually, it is missing mobile_store (old API), not 'title'. The error returned from Facebook API was confusing.